# How can I improve my answers to avoid downvoters?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, specific-answer

I try to provide high-quality answers on Stack Overflow and make a point to edit my questions if someone points out something that I missed or made a mistake on.

I [answered a question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53746372/4416750) earlier and it immediately received three downvotes and was flagged for deletion because there was a C# 8.0 feature I wasn't aware of. Well after I did some research, it turns out that the feature has not been released yet, even in the C# 8.0 preview.

I edited my question three times to provide the relevant updated information but no one changed the downvotes. How can I improve the quality of my answers to prevent something like this from happening again?

Comment: And I'm immediately downvoted here with no explanation (faster than it would take to even read the linked answer). How do you expect people to improve and conform to SO's standards if you won't even tell them *why* they were downvoted?

Comment: Lews, explaining votes is not expected and it is actually discouraged. Do not expect users to explain their votes in either questions or answers.

Comment: @yivi Fair points.

Comment: Do not worry about downvotes. Collect hats, bounties and badges ;)

Comment: I've all but given up on commenting my question downvotes. But as people put more effort in answers: if there is a concise reason to downvote an answer, I *try* to leave a comment pointing out why. If the comment is acted upon, I may take it back and delete the comment. Don't count on it, though. Sometimes I comment first and downvote later, other times the other way around.

Comment: Just keep in mind: getting downvotes is a problem. Not getting upvotes is a huge problem. Everyone should be aiming to attract upvotes, and not to "avoid downvotes". If you put it like that it is a whole different level of quality you'll be shooting for.

Comment: Based on the title I would say you can't avoid downvoters as we have no features to limit visibility of posts to a certain reputation level ... I like being pedantic ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Users are free to use their votes as they see fit. If they think an answer is not useful, they are liable to downvote.

There is no way to guarantee other users will find your posts useful. And there is no way to know if the users who voted on your post saw your edits, or were the same ones that commented on your post.

Do your due dilligence and research, make your posts as clear and generally useful as you can, and hope fo the best.

It's simply impossible to write answers so down-votes are an impossibility.

(In no way I’m saying that votes are random or unjustified, nor that you shouldn’t try write useful, well researched posts in hopes to get upvotes and no downvotes; or that you should “ignore” the signal votes provide; only that there is no sure way to avoid down votes since they are ultimately out of your control).

Comment: Saying there's nothing that they can do, just shrugging your shoulders, and saying "avoiding downvotes is impossible" is completely disingenuous here.  The answer wasn't well researched, wasn't useful, and they got plenty of feedback pointing out problems with the answer and then proceeded to *not correct those problems* and complain that they weren't getting feedback.  Just ignoring all of those things and "hoping for the best" is not a healthy way to approach situations like this.

Comment: I insist that’s impossible to write answers to “avoid downvotes”, as the question asks. I don’t care about that specific answer in any way. I do say you should do your do diligence and research when posting. I’m sorry but think your reading of my answer is obtuse.

Comment: And yet there are *lots* of things that you can do that will result in you being downvoted a *lot* less, and there are lots of things you can do in response to getting downvotes to both avoid more from being cast and to try to get those cast reversed.  Just because perfection is impossible doesn't mean you should just ignore the downvotes that you get.  You can always do better.  Giving up because perfection is impossible isn't good advice.

Comment: @Servy I don't see how this answer is implying at all that anyone should give up or ignore feedback.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton The question asks what to do to avoid getting downvotes, and the answer says, "it's impossible", and provides no other advice on how to actually avoid getting downvotes on posts.  The fact that the answer was edited to say it's not saying you should do nothing, despite providing literally nothing that you *should* do, doesn't really change that; at a minimum, the answer is useless as it doesn't actually tell anyone what they should do, even if it now admits that such things theoretically exist.

Comment: @Servy "_Just do your due dilligence and research, make your posts as clear and generally useful as you can, and hope fo the best._" is not providing advice on how to avoid getting downvotes? The answer doesn't state it's impossible to write answers without getting downvotes, it says it is impossible to _guarantee_ you will not get any downvotes, because it is out of your control, which is true. This is not an implication that all is hopeless and is not an implication that the answer is to give up and ignore feedback.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Responding to a question of, "how do I post better answers" by saying, "post answers that are useful" is just begging the question.  That's not really useful. There are plenty of things you can do to reduce the number of downvotes you get, and lots of beneficial ways to react to downvotes.  Just stating that it's impossible to avoid downvotes, instead of explaining how to reduce the number on your posts, or otherwise make them more useful, is not a good answer.  If there are useful things for the author to do in this situation then *why is the answer not mentioning any of them*.

Answer (score 17):

Start by reading the question more carefully (especially in response to downvotes, as that's an indication you missed something).  When you don't even read the question to understand what it's asking, and post an answer that's just objectively false, you're going to get downvotes, because that answer isn't useful.

That you edited your answer to include a notation that you now realize you didn't understand the question and that is the reason why you posted an *objectively incorrect answer* doesn't make it any more useful.  When you recognized that your answer was wrong, due to not understanding the question, you should simply have deleted it (if you couldn't correct to be a useful answer), rather than trying to explain why you posted an incorrect answer (which doesn't make it a useful answer).

Additionally, complaining about downvotes on your post *multiple times*, and claiming that no one is telling you what's wrong with your answer *when your answer has a dozen comments on it explaining what's wrong with it* is just going to annoy people.

Comment: I did read the question and I missed that they were using C# 8.0. Even still, the feature I was downvoted for is not even in C# 8.0 so my answer wasn't even incorrect...

Comment: @LewsTherin Clearly you didn't read the question carefully enough, as my answer says, given that you missed *a key factor of the question* which is addressed in several places in that (fairly short) question.  The fact that the feature hasn't been implemented in the preview yet doesn't make your answer that, "interfaces by design shouldn't have implementations" wrong.  They are being specifically designed *to* have implementations, it's just not quite ready yet.  That's a very different answer than what you gave.

Comment: In my experience with .NET prior to C# 8.0, what I said was accurate. In C# prior to 8.0 Interfaces not only shouldn't have implementations, they threw the error the question asker saw. I didn't even know that the default method implementations was being added to the language prior to today. In my 10 years with the .NET stack, interfaces *never* contained implementations. I think SO is way too pedantic sometimes.

Comment: @LewsTherin The fact that your answer would have been correct a year ago (or if the question was about an entirely different version, making it an entirely different question) doesn't make your answer any less wrong.  It makes it an understandable mistake, sure.  Be grateful that people pointed out your mistake, and take actions to correct it, rather than making false allegations against the people who pointed out your mistake and claiming that you didn't make a mistake.

Comment: @LewsTherin We're trying to build a giant repository of knowledge that withstands the test of time.  Being too loose with the quality standards means the knowledge base doesn't last for nearly as long.  It's supposed to be useful for the unforeseen future, so being pedantic with the requirements isn't only to be expected, but par for the course.

Comment: @fbueckert I agree to an extent but where does it end? If the feature isn't released to the general public then as of the date of my answer, then my answer isn't incorrect. How can I anticipate new features coming to the language that completely change the behavior of something that has worked the same way for almost a decade? Once someone brought up the new feature, I edited my answer to include it. What more could I do?

Comment: @LewsTherin Well, like we keep saying, doing your research before answering would help, and reading the question and understanding it properly would also have helped.  There are many correct ways to solve a problem; the more useful it is, the more it will get upvoted.  Your original answer was incorrect; there's no point in keeping it, so adding all the edits just detracts from finding the solution.  You can either completely rewrite your answer so that it solves the problem as stated, without extraneous cruft like, "Edit", or you can delete it.

Comment: @LewsTherin This isn't a case of a language feature coming out two years after you post your answer to change what the answer is.  This is a case about someone asking about a particular feature in a particular version and you not realizing that the feature exists in that version.  This isn't about "not updating an old answer when it changes over time", it's about you not knowing the answer to the question because you didn't read the question carefully enough or know enough about the subject matter to know the answer.

Comment: As far as what you could have done, well, when you found out that your answer was wrong, you just edited it to say that you didn't realize this was a language feature, and then to doubled down on an explanation of why this feature shouldn't exist, which just *isn't an answer to the question*.  What you should have done is just deleted your answer when you realized you misunderstood the question and that it's just wrong.  Your answer is *still* wrong, even now.  You haven't corrected the problems with it.

Comment: @Servy You are blowing this way out of proportion and now putting words in my mouth. I never said the feature shouldn't exist. I said, in the current released version of .NET, it doesn't exist. Even in the C# 8.0 version that OP mentioned, it is only a planned feature, *it has not been released*. No can even use the feature! The other answer that was upvoted even states that the feature is not available yet, and that it is a prototype. OP literally cannot use the feature because it isn't availble yet. That is the answer to their question and is contained in my edits.

Comment: Per discussion in these comments and comments on my original answer, I've removed all irrelevant edit information and took it down to just answer the question as asked.

Comment: @LewsTherin You didn't say, in those words, that it shouldn't exist, you just said it's against the design of the language and said what you think they should be doing instead, which pretty heavily implies as much.  Yes, the correct answer to the question (as is covered by the duplicate) is that the feature is planned but not implemented.  That doesn't mean saying, "The very idea of that feature is against the design of the language," is a correct answer.

Comment: @Servy According to [Microsoft's documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/) (which I'm sure was written prior to C# 8.0), interfaces were not designed to have implementations: `When a class or struct implements an interface, the class or struct must provide an implementation for all of the members that the interface defines. *The interface itself provides no functionality that a class or struct can inherit* in the way that it can inherit base class functionality.` I never once said or implied that feature is against the design of the language.

Comment: @LewsTherin Yes, and when the documentation ends up being written for C# 8, it will need to change.  And people continuing to make those kinds of statements when referring to C# 8+ will be wrong.  Your exact quote was, "Interfaces by design are not for adding an implementation." which is indeed very clearly saying that interfaces are designed to not have an implementation.  That you edited that out is good, but you did say that originally.

Comment: @Servy and as Microsoft's own documentation proves, interfaces were **not** initially designed to have an implementation. C# 8.0 might change that, but my answer is still correct until such time that it happens.

Comment: @LewsTherin Yes, had you posted your answer to a question *not* about C# 8, it wouldn't be wrong.  But  you didn't do that.  You posted it to a question that *is* about C# 8, where it *is* wrong.  C# has changed the design of interfaces so that they *will* be able to provide implementations now.  Arguing that your answer would have been right if posted to a completely different question doesn't change the fact that it's wrong when posted to the question you actually posted it on.

Comment: @Servy I'm not wrong about C# 8.0 either. C# 8.0 hasn't been released, and the preview build **does not have that feature**. It is ***planned***.

Comment: At this point, the conversation is just running in circles.  The answer's been updated, it seems to be better and address the question as asked, so there doesn't seem to be much point in continuing this.

Comment: @fbueckert Good point, I should have stopped long ago. My bad, I am now.